# How can I make a custom .Net Windows Form that acts like a MessageBox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

How can I make a form that behaves like a message box?

For example, I have 2 forms named `form1` and `form2`.

- `form1` contains my basic information (Name, gender, address and 1 button (educational background)).
- `form2` contains my educational background (school, school_add, button(OK) and button (Cancel)).

If I open `form1` and I click the educational background button, then `form2` will appear.  What I want is that if the user tries to click `form1` while `form2` is still open, then `form2` will blink and the user cannot manipulate `form1`. I want to require the user to click the Cancel or the OK button on `form2` before returning to `form1`, just like how a message box prevents you from using the form behind it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just set the second form to topmost, which means it will stay on top until its disposed.... You set that in the form properties.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called a **[Modal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39wcs2dh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** form.

It's very easy to do: just call `.ShowDialog(Me)` instead of `.Show()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
' Form1 button handler
Private Sub buttonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button.Click
   Dim f As New Form2()
   f.ShowDialog(Me)
End Sub
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39wcs2dh(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Load your form using .ShowDialog instead of .Show

```
Form2.ShowDialog
```